# Start neo4j server on windows

Tags: neo4j

When I try to start the server on windows:
Open a windows command prompt, go to the `neo4j` bin directory and execute **Neo4j.bat.**

I get this error message:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\app\NEO4J-~1.2\bin\windows-service-wrapper-*.jar
```

What do I need to change in the bat files that it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the * with the version of the neo4j you have downloaded.

1. go to the bin directory
2. open the `base.bat` file and look for something like this `set wrapperJarFilename=windows-service-wrapper-*.jar`
3. replace the `*` with the version of the jar file `windows-service-wrapper-4.jar` (this jar file will be in your bin directory). In my case the version is 4 so replace `*` with `4`.